# How to connect 2 network over openvpn

Tags: debian, openvpn, linux-networking, raspbian

I need to access 192.168.9.0/24 from 192.168.1.0/24 only one direction. I tried using ssh tunneling over raspberry pi(10.8.0.2) but this is not an exact solution for me.

Operating system of the raspberry pi is Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch) Raspberry pi hardware: model B

See: 
[image: My Network diagram]

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: I think I might help (and I guess others might as well) but… What is your question/need/problem?

Comment: Make NAT from 192.168.1.0/24  network to 192.168.9.0/24 network on 10.8.0.1 router. Also add ip route to 192.168.9.0/24  network via 10.8.0.2 there.

Comment: Additionally I made nat on Raspberry pi side as below and problem solved.

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.9.0/24 -o br0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.9.100